# why `gulp.src` in `gulp.watch` won't work?

Tags: gulp

I want to just build 'the only one file' I changed,not a bunch of files,
so I tried something like this

```
gulp.task('watch_html', function () {
    return gulp.watch('source/**/*.html', function (event) {
        gulp.src(event.path)
        .pipe(prettify({indent_size: 4}))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
    });
});
```

But why this won't work? 
Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a gulp package like `gulp-changed` may be able to help you out.

It provides a way to only operate on changed files in a stream. Check it out [here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-changed).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you ! This plugin works just great ! But still it is curious that why gulp.src won't work in the gulp.watch...

Comment: Please mark as answer if it's what you were looking for :D glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

You should separate the tasks :

```
gulp.task('html', function() {
  return gulp.src('source/**/*.html')
    .pipe(prettify({indent_size: 4}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
  // when modification is detected, html task is launched
  gulp.watch(['source/**/*.html'], ['html']);
```

});